# Using SVD to compress an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave, image-compression, svd

I am brand new to MATLAB but am trying to do some image compression code for grayscale images.

**Questions**

How can I use SVD to trim off low-valued eigenvalues to reconstruct a compressed image?

**Work/Attempts so far**

My code so far is:

```
B=imread('images1.jpeg');   
B=rgb2gray(B);  
doubleB=double(B);  
%read the image and store it as matrix B, convert the image to a grayscale
photo and convert the matrix to a class 'double' for values 0-255  
[U,S,V]=svd(doubleB);
```

This allows me to successfully decompose the image matrix with eigenvalues stored in variable S.

How do I truncate S (which is 167x301, class double)? Let's say of the 167 eigenvalues I want to take only the top 100 (or any n really), how do I do that and reconstruct the compressed image?

**Updated code/thoughts**

Instead of putting a bunch of code in the comments section, this is the current draft I have. I have been able to successfully create the compressed image by manually changing N, but I would like to do 2 additional things:

1- Show a pannel of images for various compressions (i/e, run a loop for N = 5,10,25, etc.)

2- Somehow calculate the difference (error) between each image and the original and graph it.

I am horrible with understanding loops and output, but this is what I have tried:

```
B=imread('images1.jpeg');  
B=rgb2gray(B);  
doubleB=im2double(B);%  
%read the image and store it as matrix B, convert the image to a grayscale  
%photo and convert the image to a class 'double'  
[U,S,V]=svd(doubleB);   
C=S;  
for N=[5,10,25,50,100]  
C(N+1:end,:)=0;  
C(:,N+1:end)=0;  
D=U*C*V';  
%Use singular value decomposition on the image doubleB, create a new matrix  
%C (for Compression diagonal) and zero out all entries above N, (which in  
%this case is 100). Then construct a new image, D, by using the new  
%diagonal matrix C.  
imshow(D);  
error=C-D;  
end
```

Obviously there are some errors because I don't get multiple pictures or know how to "graph" the error matrix

Comment: Some more information at DSP: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18673/image-compression-using-the-svd-in-matlab.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just to start, I assume you're aware that the SVD is really not the best tool to decorrelate the pixels in a single image.  But it is good practice.

OK, so we know that `B = U*S*V'`.  And we know S is diagonal, and sorted by magnitude.  So by using only the top few values of S, you'll get an approximation of your image.  Let's say `C=U*S2*V'`, where S2 is your modified S.   The sizes of U and V haven't changed, so the easiest thing to do for now is to zero the elements of S that you don't want to use, and run the reconstruction.  (Easiest way to do this: `S2=S; S2(N+1:end, :) = 0; S2(:, N+1:end) = 0;`).

Now for the compression part.  `U` is full, and so is `V`, so no matter what happens to `S2`, your data volume doesn't change.  But look at what happens to `U*S2`.  (Plot the image).  If you kept N singular values in `S2`, then only the first N rows of `S2` are nonzero.  Compression!  Except you still have to deal with `V`.  You can't use the same trick after you've already done `(U*S2)`, since more of `U*S2` is nonzero than `S2` was by itself.  How can we use S2 on both sides?  Well, it's diagonal, so use `D=sqrt(S2)`, and now `C=U*D*D*V'`.  So now `U*D` has only N nonzero rows, and `D*V'` has only N nonzero columns.  Transmit only those quantities, and you can reconstruct C, which is approximately like B.

Comment: thank you for the thorough explanation. I will take a look at this and come back if I have questions/problems.

Comment: currently this is the code I'm using: `B=imread('images1.jpeg'); 
B=rgb2gray(B);
doubleB=double(B);
[U,S,V]=svd(doubleB); 
C=S;
N=100;
C(N+1:end,:)=0;
C(:,N+1:end)=0;
D=U*C*V';
imshow(D);` and no matter what I make N, it seems that the new image is the same (and extremely sketchy looking). For reference, S is 167x301. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmm, actually, when I run imshow(doubleB) the image is just awful looking...looks nothing like the original

Comment: Try im2double(B) instead of double(B)

Comment: I just added some additional code and thoughts to the original post. Having trouble understanding how to output the image from a loop (changing N) and graphing the difference/error between compressed and original.

Comment: Look into `subplot` for showing multiple images.  And try `imagesc` instead of image to display the error image.  And/or square and average the pixels error image to get a single error metric (mean-squared-error) for each reconstruction.  Stash that metric in another vector, so you can plot N vs. MSE.

Answer (score 21):

Although this question is old, it has helped me a lot to understand SVD. I have modified the code you have written in your question to make it work.

I believe you might have solved the problem, however just for the future reference for anyone visiting this page, I am including the complete code here with the output images and graph.

Below is the code:

```
close all
clear all
clc

%reading and converting the image
inImage=imread('fruits.jpg');
inImage=rgb2gray(inImage);
inImageD=double(inImage);

% decomposing the image using singular value decomposition
[U,S,V]=svd(inImageD);

% Using different number of singular values (diagonal of S) to compress and
% reconstruct the image
dispEr = [];
numSVals = [];
for N=5:25:300
    % store the singular values in a temporary var
    C = S;

    % discard the diagonal values not required for compression
    C(N+1:end,:)=0;
    C(:,N+1:end)=0;

    % Construct an Image using the selected singular values
    D=U*C*V';


    % display and compute error
    figure;
    buffer = sprintf('Image output using %d singular values', N)
    imshow(uint8(D));
    title(buffer);
    error=sum(sum((inImageD-D).^2));

    % store vals for display
    dispEr = [dispEr; error];
    numSVals = [numSVals; N];
end

% dislay the error graph
figure; 
title('Error in compression');
plot(numSVals, dispEr);
grid on
xlabel('Number of Singular Values used');
ylabel('Error between compress and original image');
```

Applying this to the following image:
[image: Original Image]

Gives the following result with only first 5 Singular Values,

[image: First 5 Singular Values]

with first 30 Singular Values,

[image: First 30 Singular Values]

and the first 55 Singular Values,

[image: First 55 Singular Values]

The change in error with increasing number of singular values can be seen in the graph below.

[image: Error graph]

Here you can notice the graph is showing that using approximately 200 first singular values yields to approximately zero error.

Answer (score 5):

For example, here's a 512 x 512 B&W image of [Lena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna):

[image: Lena]

We compute the SVD of Lena. Choosing the singular values above 1% of the maximum singular value, we are left with just **53 singular values**. Reconstructing Lena with these singular values and the corresponding (left and right) singular vectors, we obtain a [low-rank approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) of Lena:

[image]

Instead of storing 512 * 512 = 262144 values (each taking 8 bits), we can store 2 x (512 x 53) + 53 = 54325 values, which is approximately **20% of the original size**. This is one example of how SVD can be used to do lossy image compression.

---

Here's the **MATLAB** code:

```
% open Lena image and convert from uint8 to double
Lena = double(imread('LenaBW.bmp'));

% perform SVD on Lena
[U,S,V] = svd(Lena);

% extract singular values
singvals = diag(S);

% find out where to truncate the U, S, V matrices
indices = find(singvals >= 0.01 * singvals(1));

% reduce SVD matrices
U_red = U(:,indices);
S_red = S(indices,indices);
V_red = V(:,indices);

% construct low-rank approximation of Lena
Lena_red = U_red * S_red * V_red';

% print results to command window
r = num2str(length(indices));
m = num2str(length(singvals));
disp(['Low-rank approximation used ',r,' of ',m,' singular values']);

% save reduced Lena
imwrite(uint8(Lena_red),'Reduced Lena.bmp');
```

Answer (score 0):

taking the first n max number of eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors may solve your problem.For PCA, the original data multiplied by the first ascending eigenvectors will construct your image by n x d where d represents the number of eigenvectors.