# Compressing and decompressing images

Tags: image, matlab, image-compression

I'm new to Matlab and image analysis and I'm working on image compression and decompression.

I'm trying to write a program that will be compressing and decompressing images in Matlab. Would you be able to show me a code example?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614886/using-svd-to-compress-an-image-in-matlab) to see how singular value decomposition can be used to compress images.

Comment: Thank you. I've mostly read about DCT while doing my research on this. Would you be able to guide me to a DCT sample?

Comment: [This page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/discrete-cosine-transform.html) shows how the discrete cosine transform can be used for image compression.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the DCT does a [lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression), which means that information is lost during the compression, and therefore the original image cannot be recovered. [Lossless compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) algorithms do exist, but their details are beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for that. The example code doesn't run for specific images. Could it be because the vertical resolution of the images I try isn't divisible by 8?

Comment: Yes, that's probably correct. The easiest solution would be to increase the size of the input image to the next biggest multiple of 8, by repeating the last row and/or column of pixels. You can then remove those additional pixels after the decompression is done.