# Matrix whose columns are the first $p$ left singular vectors

Tags: matrix, matlab, matrix-decomposition, svd

Let's say I have a $m \times n$ matrix $A$.  When I find its SVD, I get $p$ dominant singular values.  How do I get the $m \times p$ matrix whose columns are the first $p$ left singular vectors of $A$?

Comment: Your Question is a little unclear.  In connection with the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of a matrix, one speaks of *left-singular vectors* and *right-singular vectors*.  I suspect that if you review what the SVD (singular value decomposition) is (either for real or complex matrices), then the answer you seek about how to get the "first P singular vectors" will either be immediately obvious or at least easily stated in a precise form.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40046525/6338725).